# Firebase crashlytics not working when application has two process

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, crash-reports, crashlytics-android, firebase-crash-reporting

I am having application running with 2 process(where I'm running foreground service in separate process), and Firebase crashlytics is not able to upload crash happens in service process which is sub process.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
     FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this@ServiceClassName)
}
```